# Using pointer variables to print specific array variables

Tags: c++, arrays, function, loops, pointers

I am a C++ beginner and my task is as follows:

> Define and initialise a single-dimensional integer array. Next, define a pointer that points to the first element in the array and passes the pointer to a function.
>
> Using only pointer variables (and looping constructs), print only the array values that are exact multiples of `7` from start to finish to standard output. The only program output should be the numbers, one per line with no white space.

I have tried:

```
void print_sevens(int* nums, int length)
{
    int array[5] = { 5,8,21,43,70 };
    int* ptr = array;
    int* num = array;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        *num++;
        if (num[i] % 7 == 0) {
            cout << num[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int array[5] = { 5,8,21,43,70 };
    int* ptr = array;
    print_sevens(ptr, 5);
}
```

It compiles but does not output anything.

I am also confused about passing the pointer to a function. Should this be done in the main file or in the function file?

Comment: Why do you create a new `array` inside the function?

Comment: @Aziz the function doesn't allow me to pass an array to it as a parameter, so I wasnt sure where to put the array

Comment: You are actually passing an array (as a pointer) as a parameter to the function `print_sevens`.  You don't need to create a new array inside the function.

Comment: @Aziz ohh okay thanks

Comment: To be clear: it outputs nothing at all?

Comment: @Chipster yes nothing at all, just compiles

Comment: Which question are you asking: the one about no output or the one about passing the pointer to the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating an additional array in the `print_sevens` function, which is unnecessary as you already passed the pointer to the first element of the array created in the `main()`(i.e. `array`).

Removing that unnecessary `array` and related codes from the function will make the program run perfectly. **([See online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/I33yy4upkMGePhwZ))**

```
void print_sevens(int* nums, int length) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
        if (nums[i] % 7 == 0) 
            std::cout << nums[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

and in the `main` you only need to do the follows, as *[arrays decay to the pointer pointing to its first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)*.

```
int main() 
{
    int array[5]{ 5,8,21,43,70 };
    print_sevens(array, 5);
}
```

---

Note that,

- `num++` increments the pointer, not the underline element it is
  pointing to (due to the higher *[operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)* of `operator++` than `operator*`). If you meant to increment the element(pointee) you
  should have `(*num)++`.
- Secondly, do not practice with `using namespace std;`. Read more:
  [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score -1):

You are modifying the contents of your array when you do `*num++`.

Comment: i tried allocating a pointer to the *num variable then incrementing and printing that out but it just prints memory addresses

Comment: `*num++` is just defeference pointer, then increment pointer. Since nothing is being done to the dereferenced pointer the asker could discard the defererence and not notice a thing. All that code's doing is advancing the pointer. Demo: https://ideone.com/z19w0Q

Comment: That is not causing **the** problem, but it is **a** problem.